# No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject subclass Have you loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet?

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to save data in the local storage using Core Data and I'm getting this error :

> No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject
>   subclass 'TrackItem' so +entity is confused.  Have you loaded your
>   NSManagedObjectModel yet ?

```
@IBAction func AddTrack(_ sender: Any) {

    print("I made it to AddTrack§§§§§")

    let Trackitem = TrackItem(context: PersistenceService.context)
    Trackitem.kms = Int32(kmsField!.text!)!
    Trackitem.liters = Float(litersField!.text!)!
    Trackitem.date = textFieldPicker!.text!
    PersistenceService.saveContext()
}
```

This is the function of the button to save. Knowing that I made a CoreData model with the entity and its attributes and CreateNSObject... and I have the class and the extension of the Model. But After adding some content in the input fields and try to save the app stops working and gives me this error.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class PersistenceService {

    private init() {

    }

    static var context:NSManagedObjectContext{
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        /*
         The persistent container for the application. This implementation
         creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
         application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
         error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        */
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FillMyTank")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    static func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is most likely in PersistenceService.

Comment: I added the persistance service, do you see something wrong?

Comment: Nothing obvious. Double check that the model name is spelled correctly. Have you renamed anything like the model itself or any entities, this might be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. For me it was an annotation that I deleted before the class definition, which looks like `@objc(CLASSNAME)`. So for example:

```
@objc(Person)
public class Person
```

I have my entity codegen on `Manual/None`, then while in the datamodel I click on: Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass.